# Problema con fetch y evento de botones javascript

Tags: javascript, eventos, fetch

He creado un pequeño programa con fetch que te saca 4 fotos de la pokeapi según el nombre del pokemon que le metas, el problema es que al escribir otro pokemon y darle click al botón no funciona ni me carga nada, no se si es problema del botón o de que hice mal la petición.

```js
function mostrarFoto(){
    
  let pokemon = document.getElementById("pokemon");
  console.log(pokemon.value.toLowerCase());

    let url="https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"+pokemon.value.toLowerCase();

    fetch(url)
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(data=>mostrarFoto(data))
    .catch(error=>console.log(error));

    // let ContadorSprites=Object.keys(data.sprites).length;
    // console.log(data.sprites);
    console.log(data.sprites["front_default"]);
      document.body.innerHTML+=`<img src='${data.sprites["front_default"]}'>`;
      document.body.innerHTML+=`<img src='${data.sprites["front_female"]}'>`;
      document.body.innerHTML+=`<img src='${data.sprites["front_shiny"]}'>`;
      document.body.innerHTML+=`<img src='${data.sprites["front_shiny_female"]}'>`;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <!-- <script src="js/fetch2.js"></script> class="form-control"-->
    <input type="text" id="pokemon" class="form-control" placeholder="Introduce un Pokemon">
    <button type="button" onclick="mostrarFoto()" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Buscar</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <script src="js/fetch2.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Llamas a `mostrarFoto`-> hace un fetch -> que vuelve a llamar a `mostrarFoto` -> que vuelve a hacer un fetch -> que vuelve a llamar a `mostrarFoto` -> que hace un fetch -> que vuelve a....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba asi

```
<body>
<!-- <script src="js/fetch2.js"></script> class="form-control"-->
<input type="text" id="pokemon" class="form-control" placeholder="Introduce un Pokemon">
<button type="button" onclick="mostrarFoto()" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Buscar</button>
<br>
<br>
<div id="img"></div>
<script>
function mostrarFoto() {
    let pokemon = document.getElementById("pokemon");
    let url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/" + pokemon.value.toLowerCase();
    img.innerHTML = '';
    fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(function(data) {
            var obj = data.sprites;
            for (let elem in obj) {
                let valor = obj[elem];
                if (typeof valor === 'string') {
                    img.innerHTML += `<img src='${valor}'>`;
                }
            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
</script>
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Como te señalé en los comentarios tienes un bucle infinito, llamas a `mostrarFoto` que hace un fetch que vuelve llamar a `mostrarFoto` y así sucesivamente

La solución es crear otra función para poner las imágenes

```js
function mostrarFoto(){
    
  let pokemon = document.getElementById("pokemon");
  console.log(pokemon.value.toLowerCase());

    let url="https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"+pokemon.value.toLowerCase();
    fetch(url)
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(data=>colocarFotos(data))
    .catch(error=>console.log(error));

}

function colocarFotos(data){

    console.log(data.sprites["front_default"]);
      document.body.innerHTML+=`<img src='${data.sprites["front_default"]}'>`;
      document.body.innerHTML+=`<img src='${data.sprites["front_female"]}'>`;
      document.body.innerHTML+=`<img src='${data.sprites["front_shiny"]}'>`;
      document.body.innerHTML+=`<img src='${data.sprites["front_shiny_female"]}'>`;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <!-- <script src="js/fetch2.js"></script> class="form-control"-->
    <input type="text" id="pokemon" class="form-control" placeholder="Introduce un Pokemon">
    <button type="button" onclick="mostrarFoto()" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Buscar</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <script src="js/fetch2.js"></script>
</body>
```